# Is there a way in Rails to get a unique key based on the last deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm trying to implement caching and storing a key called chat_url per organization.  I would like to invalidate the cache every time we do a deployment via capistrano, and wondered if there was a way to store the cache key with a unique deployment identifier that would be updated on each deploy. The key definition would be something like `"chat_url_#{org_id}_#{unique_key}"`

Ie: `Rails.cache.fetch('chat_url_123_675467')` for the lifespan of a deployment, and, in a month if we do another deploy would change to `Rails.cache.fetch('chat_url_123_121212')` and force an update of the cache.

I think the asset pipeline is rebuilt and given a new key so I could potentially hack a way to grab the new identifier, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: so you ask for a way to generate a new unique key each time deploy, am I right? then you need to save it to database so `Rails.cache.fetch` can get that new key?

Comment: Exactly @LongNguyen, the caching would behave normally in real-time, but when I do a deploy, any request to the key would force a refresh.  By putting a unique deployment id in the cache key would achieve that.

Comment: why not just use `SecureRandom` to generate a random unique key each time you deploy?

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to clear the specific cache key you want in deployment process, for example you have cache named `chat_url`. Then setup your deployment process to clear cache with key `chat_url`:

```
Rails.cache.delete('chat_url')
```

Then each time you deployed, `Rails.cache.fetch('chat_url')` will have to re-fetch data.

> For more information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-delete

Comment: Thanks Long, I've updated my answer, unfortunately we may need to store a key for each organization, so deleting the cache may not be an option.  I wish we could do it in the deploy, might still be an option though.

Comment: I added a comment to your question.